# Sending Ajax data to Handler php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to populate a friends list.  Here is what I have:

```
<script>
    var username = $_GET['profile_username'];

    $(document).ready(function(){

    function ajaxfriendsdefault(){

        $.ajax({

            url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:username,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#data_friends').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
 });


    function ajaxfriends(){

        $.ajax({

            url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:username,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#data_friends').html(data);
            }
        });
      }


</script>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="data_friends"></ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="ViewAllFriends" name="ViewAllFriends" value="View All Friends" onclick="ajaxfriends()">
  </div>
```

I'm sending this to the following handler `ajax_load_profile_friends.php`  I have here the following:

```
    global $con;

    if(isset($_POST['ViewAllFriends'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'"); 
    } else {
        //Default query limits results to 5
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,5"); 
    }           


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $row['profile_pic']; 
        $row['username'];

        echo "<li><a class='thumbnail pull-left' href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
                <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $row['username'] . "'>
              </a></li>";

    }
```

For `ajaxfriendsdefault()` I'd like to show friends to a limit of 5.  When the View All Friends button is clicked, I'd like to display all of the users friends.

The problems - on page load the initial 5 friends do not display.  When View All Friends is clicked, only 5 display & I'm getting the following error.  `Notice: Undefined variable: username in`

The data username has been defined as `var username = $_GET['profile_username'];`  I'm certain this is the problem, but am unsure on how to correct.  If I were to define it on the page in php it would be `$username = $_GET['profile_username'];`  Being new to ajax I'm unclear on how to define this & send.  Help! :) I'm also not sure why the initial 5 friends aren't showing?  Shouldn't `$(document).ready(function(){` fire this?

Comment: `data:{'username':username}` try

Comment: use ajax  "dataType": "json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declared variable as locally remove `var`  from `var username = <?php echo $username; ?>` make variable global then you can access inside the function. second thing you need to  check first you are receiving variable or not through `$_GET['profile_username'];`

you can check your variable is available or not

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['profile_username'])) {
    $username=$_GET['profile_username'];
    echo $username;
}
?>
```

then you can try like this

```
function ajaxfriends(){

    $.ajax({

        url:'includes/handlers/ajax_load_profile_friends.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: { 
            'username': <?php echo $username; ?>
        },

        success: function(data) {
            $('#data_friends').html(data);
        }
    });
  }
```

and you need to change

```
 if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'"); 
        }
```

instead

```
if(isset($_POST['ViewAllFriends'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
            $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'"); 
        }
```

in  `ajax_load_profile_friends.php` and for default item body should be like this and remove `else` condition from  `ajax_load_profile_friends.php`

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="data_friends">
        <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['profile_username'])) {
            $username=$_GET['profile_username'];

        //Default query limits results to 5
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,5"); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $row['profile_pic']; 
        $row['username'];

        echo "<li><a class='thumbnail pull-left' href='" . $row['username'] . "'>
                <img src='" . $row['profile_pic'] . "' title='" . $row['username'] . "'>
              </a></li>";

    }
}
  ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="ViewAllFriends" name="ViewAllFriends" value="View All Friends" onclick="ajaxfriends()">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this; tried it and same thing.  Undefined variable: username

Comment: I am indeed receiving $_GET['profile_username'];  I just echoed & it's there.

Comment: The php is firing backwards.  weird.  When the page loads nothing happens.  When I click View All Friends it displays only 5 friends, the else query.  I don't understand why ajaxfriendsdefault() is not firing and returning the else query.  The if query is suppose to run when View All Friends isset...?

Comment: The View All Friends button now displays all friends without error (Thankyou).  But I still can't get the else query to fire with document.ready()

Comment: Originally I wasn't using ajax, however I'm populating in a while loop.  Thought it would be better if I used one loop within the handler.

Comment: That was it :D  I appreciate your help on this @Rahul Shrivastava

Comment: i am glad to help you its time to delete comment

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var username = $_GET['profile_username'];
```

to this:

```
var username = "<?php echo($_GET['profile_username']); ?>";
```

try this into your ajax functions:

```
data: { 
    'username': username
},
```

Instead of this:

```
data:username,
```

Into your php I think you need to get username like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['ViewAllFriends'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        //Query to run if button ViewAllFriends submitted
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username'"); 
    } else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        //Default query limits results to 5
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE friend_array LIKE '$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username,%' OR friend_array LIKE '%,$username' LIMIT 0,5"); 
    }
```

Because you don't enter into the `if` condition but into the else condition because `$_POST['ViewAllFriends']` is not set.

Try this please

If is ok remove duplicate code and you can take `$username = $_POST['username'];` out of `if else statement`

Comment: I tried this but am getting same response.  Undefined variable: username

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri dear he is not talking  about $_POST['username'] he is talking about  var username = $_GET['profile_username'];

Comment: Getting somewhere.  I tried this earlier, not sure why it worked (somewhat better this time)  I inserted $username = $_POST['username']; & now when I click View All Friends I get 5 friends.  When the page loads there are no friends displaying.  No errors on username though, so that's a plus.

Comment: why wouldn't $(document).ready(function(){ fire the query and display 5 friends on page load.  And it seems now that View All Friends runs the query w/ a limit of 5? weird.

Comment: try to call the function ajaxfriendsdefault directly inside document.ready() or the other function

Comment: I'm new to ajax so I'm not sure I understand.  Am I not calling ajaxfriendsdefault() within document.ready?  It's within the { }

Comment: no.. writhe this for example to call the function immediately ajaxfriendsdefault();

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you clarify?

Comment: if you want to call the function immediately you need to call te function like this: ajaxfriendsdefault();
If is  not clear, try to open a new question here wht the problem :D It's better

Comment: You mean like this - (document).ready(function ajaxfriendsdefault(){